# Non-integral variables in AnyDice

Tags: anydice

Is there a way to have non-integer variables in AnyDice? (E.g. for each level of critical I need to hit by at least 5.5: first critical level needs 6, second 11, third 17, fourth 23, etc.)

Comment: Although AnyDice is on topic here, video games are not. This makes this question an odd corner case. However, it remains that this site is [for questions regarding analogue roleplaying games](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and it does not serve the site's purposes to accept AnyDice questions that aren't about RPGs, so I'm closing this as off topic.

Comment: understood. my apologies.

Comment: No harm, no foul! It's an unfortunate administrative necessity rather than any value judgement. You might be able to get help at our sibling sites of [statistics.se] or [math.se] SE though. Good luck!

Comment: As I see it, even though the question arises from a video game, if "video game" weren't mentioned, it would be on-topic. Therefore I see no reason to put it off-topic, since it's a problem very well applied to RPG.

Comment: Questions that are not fundamentally tied to the same basic point need to be asked separately, so in case this can be reopened, I've edited out your second question.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans We're not going to be a clearinghouse for any and all AnyDice questions. We are an RPG site, and *AnyDice programming questions* are only on-topic exactly as far as they are RPG questions. This would be on-topic for Stack Overflow perhaps, so there is no possible need to artificially tweak it to make it seem on-topic here.

Comment: In any case, as far as I know, the answer is "no, there isn't."